# ngx-bootstrap datepicker input not updated for incorrect value

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I would like to known if it's a bug on datepicker, or I must to write my handler for this (to reproduce use the first example from http://ngx-bootstrap.surge.sh/#/datepicker):

- click on input (value is 12/08/2017),
- the datepicker is shown
- encode    something like "bla-bla-bla" and click outside the input
- result: input value is empty
- click on input (the datepicker is shown),
- encode the same "bla-bla-bla" and click outside the input
- result: input value is not empty, but "bla-bla-bla"

Comment: Seems like an issue to me. You can track its progress here https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3247

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in rc.0
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#basic

There are were such issue, but it was fixed